# Get the Act count based on the product position mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to get count of current act where a product has reached, kindly see my graphical description bellow and 
kindly offer your suggestions (MYSQL)

tracking t

```
product | Act | Date
--------+-----+------------
a       | I   | date-x
a       | R   | date-x
a       | C   | date-x
b       | I   | date-x
b       | R   | date-x
b       | C   | date-x
c       | I   | date-x
d       | I   | date-x
e       | I   | date-x
e       | R   | date-x
e       | C   | date-x
f       | I   | date-x
f       | R   | date-x
---------------------------
```

As shown above you can see my example table. What I would like to do is 
get the count of Acts for where each product has reached, for example we can see that product 'a','b' and 'e' have all reached Act 'C'
The result should therefore be in this manner ignoring all the acts they were before, essentially we are only taking count of their current position

All products that have reached Act 'C' are 3 as shown below

More info, if a product has gone past a given act, its not counted as part of that act but rather of the new act,  product 'a' and 'b' can not be counted as part of act 'I' since they are currently at act 'C', so we count them as part of act 'C'

Result table

```
Act  | Count
------------------
I    |   2       //c,d
-----------------
C    |   3       //a, b, e
--------------
R    |    1      //f
-------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,product CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
,act CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(product,act)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (product,act) VALUES
('a','I'),
('a','R'),
('a','C'),
('b','I'),
('b','R'),
('b','C'),
('c','I'),
('d','I'),
('e','I'),
('e','R'),
('e','C'),
('f','I'),
('f','R');

SELECT act
     , COUNT(*) cnt 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT product
                   , MAX(id) max_id 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY product
            ) y 
           ON y.product = x.product 
          AND y.max_id = x.id
     ) n 
 GROUP 
    BY act;
+-----+-----+
| act | cnt |
+-----+-----+
| C   |   3 |
| I   |   2 |
| R   |   1 |
+-----+-----+
```